# NextJS 13 App Images Not Loading On Route Hosted with GitHub Pages

Tags: next.js, github-pages, next.js13

I am trying to host a very simple NextJS 13 site using GitHub pages, however i noticed that weird behaviour that only seems to be affecting Safari (iOS + MacOS).

On initial load, images are displayed correctly, however on route i get a 404 with images.

Safari (Broken):
[image]

Chrome (working as expected):
[image]

This is my Github repo:
https://github.com/ayush-lal/boilerplate-nextjs

TIA

EDIT:

```js
// next.config.js

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const repo = "boilerplate-nextjs";
const assetPrefix = `/${repo}/`;
const basePath = `/${repo}`;

const nextConfig = {
  trailingSlash: true,

  output: "export",
  basePath: basePath,
  assetPrefix: assetPrefix,
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you use two-dots in your the image src attribute. You don't need this. If you serve static files in your public folder, you can just use slash mark `(/)`. E.g. `/my-img.png`

In your project, you need to specify the directory where the project is located. Because when you use (/), it will redirect to the root directory, like this: "http://yourdomain.com/". But your project is not located there, it is located here: "http://yourdomain.com/project-name/".

**Replace this code:**

```js
<Image
  className="relative dark:drop-shadow-[0_0_0.3rem_#ffffff70] dark:invert"
  src="../next.svg"
  alt="Next.js Logo"
  width={180}
  height={37}
  priority
/>
```

**With this one:**

```js
<Image
  className="relative dark:drop-shadow-[0_0_0.3rem_#ffffff70] dark:invert"
  src="/boilerplate-nextjs/next.svg"
  alt="Next.js Logo"
  width={180}
  height={37}
  priority
/>
```

**In addition:**

- You do not need to import files in the public folder.
- Do not use another name in `/publics`, or `/public` etc.
- Do not use `./img.png`, or `../img.png` to access the file.

**Further readings:**

[Static Assets](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets)

[How to create a public folder?](https://medium.com/frontendweb/how-to-create-a-static-site-public-folder-in-next-js-6e8b623ab0d4)

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, that actually works however i thought i had that covered in asset prefix? I have added my config to the original post

Comment: @yush glad it helps. Unfortunately they still say the same way with the `basePath`: "When using the `next/image` component, you will need to add the `basePath` in front of `src`." and also `assetPrefix` configurations are not the correct approaches to solve this issue for now.